# What will be the structure of JSON string inside POST array

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x, jettison

Here is my Java program that trying to send JSON object to the server. I'm using Apache HTTPClient for HTTP requests and Jettison as JSON library.

I have few question about this.

1. What will be the structure of JSON string inside POST array. something like `{xxxxx:{userId:userId, blha, blha, blha.........}}`
2. If I need to get just the  JSON string (No need to convert to object) from POST array in server side. How to do that? In php we do like this   `echo $_POST["xxxxxxx"];`
3. Usually there is a name for each data in the POST array. but below program doesnt specify any name for JSON object. What will be the name(xxxxxxx) for below JSON string inside POST array.

---

```
string base_url = "https://abc.com/";
string username = "test_user";
string password = "test_user_pw";
string client_id = "test_user123";
string client_secret = "test_user1234567";
string login_url = base_url + "session/login";

CloseableHttpClient wf_client = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent(client_id + "/1.0").build();
HttpPost login_post = new HttpPost(loginUrl);
JSONObject login_object = new JSONObject();
try {
    login_object.put("userId", username);
    login_object.put("password", password);
    login_object.put("clientId", client_id);
    login_object.put("clientSecret", client_secret);
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}

StringEntity post_entity = new StringEntity(login_object.toString(), jason_content_type);
login_post.setEntity(post_entity);
CloseableHttpResponse responce = wf_client.execute(login_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions following your same structure

- You are right, that's the structure of JSON string. The exact syntax can be found in the [JSON.org website](http://json.org/).

Example:

```
{ 
   "userId" : "Username",
   "array"  : [ "1", "2", "3" ],
   "object" : {
      "objectId" : "bkadakdbk",
      ...
   }
}
```

- In Java you have to read the data that comes in the HTTP request in the server side (usually a servlet):

Example:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

- In Java when you make a POST request like that usually you are sending the JSON Object as the contents of the request, so there is no parameter array in the server side, that's why you have to read the contents of the request itself as in my previous example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but what do you mean by `You are right, that's the structure of JSON string` I'm looking for the exact structure of the string. If I need to generate same JSON string by just concatenating the strings. What would be the format?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya ah, ok. See my updated answer then, I added a link to the exact JSON syntax and an example. Hope it helps.